# Chrome ugly message when autofill is disabled

Tags: google-chrome, autocomplete

Since Chrome recently upgraded, I've started to see the message "This web page has disabled automatic filling for this form." all over my website when form controls are clicked (OK, accidently double clicked) where autocomplete="off" (we're talking about chat rooms etc where the browser really doesn't need to remember previous messages sent).

It's pretty ugly, does anybody know how to disable this? I can't find much information on the web, other than things dating back to 2010 just saying that this is a feature. The thing is, it's only just started happening for me on the latest version, same for another computer running Chrome.

Any ideas?

Cheers

Comment: just noticed this issue today as well...

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Just stumbled upon the same problem and found a simple fix.

You have to add the autocomplete attribute directly to the input field NOT to the whole form.

**This code works:**

```
<form method="get" action="index.php">
    <input type="text" name="q" autocomplete="off">
```

And this won't

```
<form method="get" action="index.php" autocomplete="off">
    <input type="text" name="q">
```

Comment: <form method="get" action="index.php" autocomplete="off">
        <input type="text" name="q" autocomplete="off">
does NOT work either, so make sure you don't leave autocomplete at the form tag after adding to the inputs.

Comment: If you're building a widget in jQuery, you can disable it via `$('#input').prop('autocomplete',false);`

Comment: Could not get this to work. However I found that if you have an <input type="text" id="MySearchField" placeholder="Search user..." /> google still identifies as a user field and autofill it. If I change placeholder to not contain the word "user", it works.

Answer (score -3):

```html
It Works for me :)
Guys you just need to add this code under the form tag, please check below:

<form>
<!-- fake fields are a workaround for chrome autofill getting the wrong fields-->
    <input type="text" name="fakeusernameremembered" style="display: none;" />
    <input type="password" name="fakepasswordremembered" style="display: none;" />
   <!--It helps me to remove the autofill in Chrome-->

..........

</form>
```